# Editing Wordnet Dictionary using EXTJWNL

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

I wanted to add a new synset to Wordnet using the [extjwnl library](http://extjwnl.sourceforge.net/). In order to do this, I wrote the following sample code. After saving, I observe that the new synonym and word do get added, but the semantic pointer created (which identifies the hyponymy relation) is not saved. How do I relate the pointer to the dictionary?

```
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream(propsFile));
        Dictionary dictionary = Dictionary.getInstance();
        Iterator<Synset> synsets = dictionary.getSynsetIterator(POS.NOUN);

        dictionary.edit();
        Synset newSynset = new Synset(dictionary, POS.NOUN);
        IndexWord newWord = new IndexWord(dictionary, "hublabooboo", POS.NOUN, newSynset);
        Synset topmostSynset = synsets.next();
        Pointer newPointer = new Pointer(PointerType.HYPONYM, topmostSynset, newSynset);
        dictionary.save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you add pointer to the synset's list of pointers:

```
  topmostSynset.getPointers().add(newPointer);
```

If the pointer is symmetric (like hypernym, which has a mirror one: hyponym), and dictionary.getManageSymmetricPointers() then the reverse pointer (e.g. hyponym) is added automatically.

By the way, by this code Synset topmostSynset = synsets.next(); it looks like you infer that the first returned synset from the synset iterator is the "entity" one. But this is not guaranteed anywhere. This is dictionary-dependent: might work for file-based, but most likely won't for map-based and unpredictable for database-based.

Source : [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/extjwnl/forums/forum/1333399/topic/5774875)